# Rails app deployed with Passenger just displays index of app's public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am trying to deploy a Rails application on Ubuntu 9.04 using Passenger.

As far as I can see, I have everything configured correctly; however when I point my browser at my domain, all I see is the index of the app's public directory.

My hunch is that Passenger is not starting up - at the bottom of [just-plain-folks.co.uk](http://just-plain-folks.co.uk) there's no reference to Passenger at all.  There's nothing interesting in the log files.

This is my config:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf

<IfModule passenger_module>
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
</IfModule>
```

---

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

---

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/just-plain-folks.co.uk

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@just-plain-folks.co.uk
    ServerName just-plain-folks.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.just-plain-folks.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/just-plain-folks.co.uk/public_html/
    ErrorLog /srv/www/just-plain-folks.co.uk/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/just-plain-folks.co.uk/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

`/srv/www/just-plain-folks.co.uk/public_html/` is a simlink to the public directory of my application

---

If there's anything else that might be useful in diagnosing this, let me know.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is your app's public directory "public_html" or "public"? If the former, why did you rename it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ditching the symlink and pointing directly as public. I believe passenger is a little magic in this area as to how it detects the rails app.

Even if the symlink source was called public, I suspect it would still be looking for a rails_root in `/srv/www/just-plain-folks.co.uk/`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You've no idea how much hair I've torn out over this.

Comment: Or you can use the PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot option and leave the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated: I missed the fact that you're trying to serve from the docroot)

Try turning off MultiViews

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ...

  <Directory /srv/www/just-plain-folks.co.uk/public_html>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This still gives the same result - but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I've now added that, and I still get the same results.  But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the similar issue with Sinatra, Phusion Passenger and Apache. My public directory was nested somewhere in deep, and the same thing with the views directory.

So, following configurations made my app running.

- In apache's conf file, instead of `/home/me/projects/fantasy-app/somewhere/nested/public`, I just had to use `/home/me/projects/fantasy-app/public` in the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` directives.
- In my `app.rb` which `onfig.ru` refers to, I had the following:

  ```
  set :public_folder, 'build/development/public'
  set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "build/development/views") }
  ```